# Trouble with reference/value mixups?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm tweaking a function that reverses the values of a container denoted by iterators begin and end.

Why does this work:

```
template<class Bi> void reverse(Bi begin, Bi end){
    while (begin!= end) {
        --end;
        if (begin != end)
            swap(*begin++, *end);
    }
}
```

but not this?

```
template<class Bi> void reverse(Bi begin, Bi end){
    while (begin != end) {
        --end;
        if (begin != end){
            Bi temp = begin;
            Bi temp2 = end;
            *begin = *temp2;
            *end = *temp;
            begin++;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles just fine, but I must be misunderstanding something about assigning iterators equal to each other, because when I go to reverse a vector, say, of values 1 through 5, I end up with 5 through 1 in the first one, but the second one yields the values 5, 4, 3, 4, 5.
I don't understand this behavior, what's wrong here?

Comment: By the way, you might like to use [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap).

Comment: @KerrekSB: If you are going to suggest prebuilt solutions, you can go the whole nine yards and suggest `std::reverse` rather than rolling your own. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing the concept of the iterator and the value. In the second approach you copy the iterators, but not the values: `begin` and `temp` refer to the same element, so do `end` and `temp2`. When you do `*begin = *temp2;` the first element is set to 5, when you later do `*end=*temp` the first element (already set to 5) is copied to the last position, leaving both the first and the last position being `5`.

What you need to do is copying the *values*, not the iterators.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
Bi temp = begin;
Bi temp2 = end;
```

The first line assigns the iterator position `begin` refers to to `temp`. So now `temp` refers to the same position in the container as `begin`.

Then you modify the *value* stored at that position:

```
*begin = *temp2;
```

Of course, `temp` still refers to that position, therefore `*temp` now also represents the modified value.

Therefore, this:

```
*end = *temp;
```

assigns the wrong value to `*end` (in fact, it does not assign any new value at all).

Comment: Thanks for helping, I knew I was forgetting something like that. @jogojapan